# Caps lock key on MacBook Pro does not lock

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, capslock

How do I activate caps lock on my MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard?

I've tried everything. Neither the LED goes on, nor the capital letters lock. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure caps lock isn't disabled in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Modifier Keys*.

[image]